# How to write the command in Apache IoTDB so the settings can intercept part of the customized sql statements?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know if Apache IoTDB cannot execute `select * from (select val from root.gn.**) limit 1000` this kind of query statement? Are there any alternative to this statement? My use case is that I want the internal sql to be dynamic and not fixed. I already setup a page and hope that the page can intercept the customized sql statements. Therefore, anyone know how can I write my statement to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar of the `limit` command in Apache IoTDB is already executing at last for a query statement, therefore you can use `limit offset` to automatically pass your customized sql statement part to the intercept function you need.